# Conditional transformation in R

Tags: r, if-statement

Consider the following data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("01","01","02"),
                 b = c(101,101,101),
                 c = c(101,147,101),
                 d = c(100,200,500),
                 e = c(200,400,1000))
```

And:

```
agg <- data.frame(f = c("01","01","02","02"),
                  g = c("V1","V2","V1","V3"))
```

I want to change column `a` in `df` using `agg`. That is, if `a = 01` then it should be changed to `V1` and so on. However, in some cases some `a` in `df` goes into multiple names in `g` in `agg`. For instance, both `01` and `02` goes into `V1`. In that case, I want to calculate the average. However, I only want to calculate the average for `d` and `e` in `df`. That is, column `b` and `c` in `df` should be fixed. So I want following data frame:

```
    a   b   c   d   e
1   V1  101 101 300 600
2   V2  101 101 100 200
3   V1  101 147 200 400
4   V2  101 147 200 400
5   V3  101 101 500 1000
```

As can be seen, column `d` and `e` in row `1` is an average.

How can I do that in **R**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can `merge` `df` with `agg` and take `mean` for every value of `g`, `b` and `c`.

```
aggregate(cbind(d, e)~g + b + c, merge(df, agg, by.x = 'a', by.y = 'f'), mean)

#   g   b   c   d    e
#1 V1 101 101 300  600
#2 V2 101 101 100  200
#3 V3 101 101 500 1000
#4 V1 101 147 200  400
#5 V2 101 147 200  400
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `tidyverse` you can take this approach. You can merge your two data frames as below. This assumes that the average taken is based on matched columns g, b, and c.

```
library(tidyverse)

agg %>%
  inner_join(df, by = c("f" = "a")) %>%
  group_by(g,b,c) %>%
  summarise(d = mean(d),
            e = mean(e)) %>%
  rename(a = g)
```

**Output**

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
# Groups:   a, b [3]
  a         b     c     d     e
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 V1      101   101   300   600
2 V1      101   147   200   400
3 V2      101   101   100   200
4 V2      101   147   200   400
5 V3      101   101   500  1000
```

Answer (score 1):

An option using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(agg)[df, on = .(f = a)][, lapply(.SD, mean), .(g, b, c), .SDcols = d:e]
#   g   b   c   d    e
#1: V1 101 101 300  600
#2: V2 101 101 100  200
#3: V1 101 147 200  400
#4: V2 101 147 200  400
#5: V3 101 101 500 1000
```